# Transition in VueJS when data change don't work

Tags: vuejs2, transition

I have a problem to understand how to work with Transitions and state change in Vue.

Tihs is my component :

```
<template>
<section id="place" class="row">
    <transition class="fade">
        <div v-if="place" id="place-title" class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center bg-dark text-white">
            <h1>{{ place.name }}</h1>
        </div>
    </transition>
    <div id="place-picture">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/394/221">
    </div>
    <div id="place-description" class="pt-3 pb-3 p">
        <p class="text-justify mb-0" style="font-size: small"><span>{{ place.abstractDescription }}</span>
            <strong>Lire plus</strong>
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
<script>

    export default {
        name: "place",
        props: [],
        computed: {
            place() {
                return this.$store.getters.place
            }
        },
        mounted() {

        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
        transition: opacity .5s;
    }

    .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```

The transition don't work when the data of Place change. I don't figure why ...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try with `v-bind:class="{ fade: place }"`

Answer (score 1):

The data for place is inside the  tags, and the transition will apply depending on whether the element inside (the div inside transition) is **inserted or removed,**, which it isn't, as only the data for place is changing. I'm also guessing that place may be already initialised in the state, so the transition will only run again if the value of place is null and then populated - depending on whether it's true from v-if="place". Setting the place to null in the computed property if it's empty in the store may solve your issue.

Comment: You're right et thanks to explain the behabiour. My problem is the computed property is never null. Because there is a initialised value in the store for the loading and after that, if a change the place, the data is always set for something :/